# Stop Chrome from caching images

Tags: google-chrome, caching

Is there anyway to finetune what Chrome caches? I.e. I do not want it to cache images. If this could be further finetuned, i.e. define types and sizes (over which no caching would be done) or even exclude specific sites from image caching.

Answer (score 0):

This is an insanely late response,

But you should be able to stop caching from files if you add a 'random' string to the url as a parameter. Often times a new date  string is used to accomplish this.

Chrome will not be able to match this file with the one already cached and thus it will reload it.